# Is my Amazon sword flowering?

Tags: aquatic-plants

I have a mature Amazon sword in a 60L tropical tank which recently shot out a single stem with no leaves. It has now reached the surface of the tank, and extended out 2" above the water line.

Is it a flower stem? Or is it reproducing vegetatively?

[image: Image of the stem]

There's nothing on the surface yet.

Excuse the algae, the 2 bristle nose pleco's are on strike.

Comment: That certainly looks like an Amazon sword , not any crypt. I never had luck with swords but I think that is a  runner starting new plants.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57024040#57024040

Comment: I ended up cutting it off. There's no room for another in the tank, and I can't plant it on elsewhere.